# Make a control dynamic recognize another

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic

i have an application Windows Form where i created dynamic controls and i need program events like Keypress but i can't make it 'cause they don't know each other once they just exists in runtime. (i' Sorry: English by google Tradutor)

Comment: What do you mean by recognize each other? Do the controls need to know about each other or is it just the containing form that needs to know about them? Or are you just trying to hook up events? Please show your code where you are creating them.

Comment: i think they really need know each other 'cause an C1 control event will do something in C2 (a second control)

Comment: Please post code that creates controls and code from event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are creating your dynamic variables locally:

```
ComboBox c1 = new Combobox(); 
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
```

Changing jacqijvv's answer a bit to look more like what I believe you are trying to achieve. I'm also going to assume that you have multiple textbox/combobox pairs that are related to each other so you could store them in a dictionary object to retrieve them later in the event handler:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Dictionary<TextBox, ComboBox> _relatedComboBoxes;
    public Dictionary<ComboBox, TextBox> _relatedTextBoxes;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _relatedComboBoxes = new Dictionary<TextBox, ComboBox>();
        _relatedTextBoxes = new Dictionary<ComboBox, TextBox>();

        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.Text = "Button1";
        textBox.KeyDown += textBox_KeyDown;

        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        // todo: initialize combobox....
        comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;


        // add our pair of controls to the Dictionaries so that we can later
        // retrieve them together in the event handlers
        _relatedComboBoxes.Add(textBox, comboBox);
        _relatedTextBoxes.Add(comboBox, textBox);

        // add to window
        this.Controls.Add(comboBox);
        this.Controls.Add(textBox);

    }

    void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        TextBox textBox = _relatedTextBoxes[comboBox];
        // todo: do work
    }

    void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        // find the related combobox
        ComboBox comboBox = _relatedComboBoxes[textBox];

        // todo: do your work

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks everybody,
maybe I was not able to explain right, but the response of BradRem was exactly what I wanted. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Create an instance of the button
    TextBox test = new TextBox();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Set button values
        test.Text = "Button";

        // Add the event handler
        test.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.KeyPressEvent);

        // Add the textbox to the form
        this.Controls.Add(test);
    }


    // Keypress event
    private void KeyPressEvent(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(test.Text);
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: jacqijw, thanks for your help, but i did it. and i wrote the wrong event. was the KeyDown
what i wanna do seems like:

Comment: ComboBox c1 = new Combobox(); TextBox t1 = new TextBox. and Depending on c1.SelectedIndex i try Enabled or not t1

Comment: But it did not work, because when I'm in the keyDown t1 c1's just not there

Comment: Okay so let me get this right now? Do you want to have a textbox with a keypress event to bring up a combobox?

Comment: No. I have a dinamic created ComboBox where when pressed key  is "Enter" he falls on ComboBox.KeyDown and if(ComboBox.SelectedItem.equals("Date")) t1.MaxLenght = 10, else if(ComboBox.SelectedItem.Equals("Name")) t1.MaxLenght = 50; But into ComboBox.KeyDown the t1 didn't exists